# SQL Oracle - How to save the query output with spool on a text file?

Tags: text, save, output, spool

I'm using spool to save the output of my query into a text file but what is actually doing is save the sql commands into the file.

I have:

```
SPOOL D:\sqltestes\sql_test.txt
SELECT max(column1) from my_table;
SPOOL OFF;
```

And this, is writting on the text file the "SELECT max(column1) from my_table;" and not the result of the query...
Why?

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using Sql Developer or Toad.
I already [answered this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967600/spool-command-doesnt-save-result-in-query/28967707#28967707). There is a difference between Run Statement and Run Script. Try Run Script.

Comment: `Run Script` really does the trick as compared to `Run Statement`. Can anybody shed some light on this?