# SPOOL command doesnt save result in query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I'm using SQL Developer and I'm trying to save result of a query into the text file using spool command.

```
spool D:\file.txt
SELECT * FROM TABLE
SPOOL OFF
```

When I open created file it only has my query in it: 
"SELECT * FROM TABLE"
but not result of it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to execute it with a query which returns fewer rows to see if you have any other problems. After you make it work, try your query. 
Also there is a difference between Run Statement and Run Script.

In the following query

```
spool '/home/atilla/file.txt'

SELECT * FROM DUAL;

SPOOL OFF
```

If I use Run Statement, I get following file

```
   \> SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

If I use Run Script, I get following file

```
\> SELECT * FROM DUAL
DUMMY
-----
X
```

Comment: I made a query that returns only one row and now in the file there is also line "spool off" but still no results

Comment: @AlexPoole As I understand, commenter clearly says "When I try SPOOL"

Comment: I read it differently, but I found most likely culprit therefore no need for beating around the bush.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I was using run statment the whole time. Using run script works just fine. What a stupid mistake :P

Comment: @matip If this saved your problem, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you're not executing the query, just entering it into the command buffer.  You need to add a semicolon or a slash to actually execute it.