# Oracle SQL Developer - Spooling error

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

I am learning SQL at the moment, and am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Right now I am having an issue with the spool command.

I insert the file path and name the file but I keep getting an "unknown command" error.

```
spool C:\Users\user\Desktop\AAA_Task1\output.txt
set echo on
--drop table TESTTABLE;
create table TESTTABLE (TestCol int);
set echo off
spool off
```

I alternate between the create and drop statements for each test.

I run the and the table is created or dropped correctly, but I get a line one error "Unknown Command" and no text file is created.

I have attached a picture of a test command and the error.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

[image: Oracle SQL Developer - Spooling issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is difference between run script and run statement, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967600/spool-command-doesnt-save-result-in-query/28967707#28967707).
Use following commands and run script.

```
spool 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\AAA_Task1\output.txt'
set echo on
--drop table TESTTABLE;
create table TESTTABLE (TestCol int);
set echo off
spool off
```

Comment: Doh
So I simply just needed to wrap the file path in quotation marks.
I cant believe I missed that.
Thank you so much for the speedy reply.

Answer (score 0):

Making the file path in quotes did not work for me in the Oracle database.

```
spool data.txt
set echo on
Query -- the query
set echo off
spool off
```

this will save the query and output to the data.txt file in the
`"C:\Users\NELSON JOSEPH\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\data.txt"` in this location likewise username varies for others.

Comment: When you save the .sql file to any location after that when you run the script the spooled txt file will be in that location.