# Putting a condition on spool

Tags: spool

I'm trying to put a condition on spool. I want the file to be created only if my query returns at least one row.

```
define csvFile=DUMP_EMP.csv
spool &&csvFile

SELECT EMP_NO||','||EMP_NAME||','||DELETED
FROM EMP_TABLE
WHERE DELETED = 0;
spool off
```

Comment: Which SQL tool is that? And which DBMS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967600/spool-command-doesnt-save-result-in-query